# Using propertyPlaceholderConfigurer to read property in a file under WEB-INF

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

i have an xml file under WEB-INF called pretty-config.xml , it's for prettyFaces rewrite library, and i am trying to read value from property file inside it with **propertyPlaceholderConfigurer** , but it doesn't seem to work, please advise how to accomplish that, thanks.

**Update:** applicationContext

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>

                <value>classpath:messages/application.properties</value>

            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

**pretty-config.xml:** which is under WEB-INF directory

```
<url-mapping id="logout"> 
          <pattern value="/logout" /> 
          <view-id value="${request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_logout" />
</url-mapping>
```

when building the application the value isn't read from the property file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your propertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean definition should be in pretty-config.xml and your pretty config.xml should be listed in web.xml in the

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>...
```

section